# synchronizing music playing from two computers

Tags: ubuntu, music, vlc-media-player, sync

I'm a Ubuntu user who likes to use VLC media player to play my favorite music (from an internet radio station) on the computer in my bedroom. I would also like to play the same radio station using the computer in the living room, and have both playings of the same station be synchronized in time. How can I do this? (It's not simply enough to just open the radio station on the computer in the living room as well, because the two will most likely not end up synchronized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PulseAudio, you can stream the audio of one machine to one or more network sinks.  In this case, each device must be using PulseAudio.

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=983932
and [these](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#CanIusePulseAudiotoplaybackmusicontwosoundcardssimultaneously) [sections](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#HowdoIusePulseAudiooverthenetwork) in the PulseAudio FAQ.  [This](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#HowcanIusePulseAudiotostreammusicfrommymainPCtomyLANwithmultiplePCswithspeakers) might be the most relevant.